# How to create a DLL that works in both debug and release configurations when linked against?

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qmake

I am currently compiling a C++/Qt project into a dll and I would like to have one dll that works in both debug and release configuration for the end user.

It's fine if the end user cannot "step into" the library using the IDE when debugging but the idea is to distribute just one release dll and have it correctly link and run in a project that is compiled in debug.

Are there any compiler flags that I should set in qmake? I'm using QtCreator with qmake files to compile my library.

Comment: AFAIK (on Windows, anyway), once a DLL is built and linked, that's it. You can call a DLL that was linked against the non-debug system libraries from an executable that *was* built in a debug configuration.

Comment: With the MSVC tool-chain the ABI changes between debug and release. eg size/layout of the std::collections are different and types of iterators change to allow for more effective debugging.  Other compilers may also do something similar.  If you have a pure `C` interface then ABI compatibility is possible but you still have to research if heap allocation / deallocation will work between debug and release builds.

Comment: @AdrianMole I thought the same but the app doesn't work at runtime. I get some errors from Qt(is one of my 3rd party libs) that object from my library were not instantiated correctly.